# pytest : classmethods and boundmethods

Tags: python, oop, pytest

So I'm using pytest and everything works ok, but something bothers me. When I put some method in my `TestClass` definition, it's y default a bound method, but I never actually get to use "self".

Now, the "`setup_class`" (or `teardown_class`) methods are necessarily classmethods, hence I cannot call my bound methods from setup_class.

So do I define every method as classmethods and get along with it, or am I missing something ? Should I simply never use bound methods ?

```
class TestSomething(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        "do something"
        cls.bound_method(?) #how do I call it ?


    def bound_method(self):
        "do something I'd like to do in setup_class"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [setup and teardown methods in a class](http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown)

```
def setup_method(self, method):
    """ setup any state tied to the execution of the given method in a
    class.  setup_method is invoked for every test method of a class.
    """

def teardown_method(self, method):
    """ teardown any state that was previously setup with a setup_method
    call.
    """
```

That runs on every test method (bound test function) defined in the class